# PHP Get row 'id' from MySQL query results

Tags: php, mysql, fetch

I read somewhere (sorry I forgot where), that there is a way to associate an index number to rows fetched from an MySQL query result using a native PHP function (the person was not sure about the syntax so he didn't wrote it). For example:

The usual way:

```
$count = 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    echo "<li> ". $count ."id: " . $row['id'] . " lon: " . $row['lon']. ", lat: ". $row['lat'].", ". $row['road']. " </li>";
    $count++;
}
```

I know that thinking of this other way is not that important, but I'm just curious if there really is a function for that purpose.

Comment: $row['id'], it's right there...Or do you just want to retrieve the id and not the rest? Or? Row count? row number? not clear to me, sorry..

Comment: Doesn't the table you're fetching from has it's own primary key?

Comment: Were you thinking of [mysql_num_rows](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) (deprecated) to retrieve the count? Then loop over result using that? (not recommended)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can add rownum to your results array, if you edit your sql like

```
SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 as rownum, p.* FROM MYTABLE p , (SELECT @rownum:=0) r
```

so the loop like

```
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
        echo "<li> ". $row['rownum'] ."id: " . $row['id'] . " lon: " . $row['lon']. ", 
        lat: ". $row['lat'].", ". $row['road']. " </li>";

    }
```

Comment: So there is no native PHP-MySQL function for that. Thanks for the **@rownum**. I didn't know that.